# classification on time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification

This is a problem related to classification on a time-ordered sequence of events.

I have a data set that consists on a map between two types, **A** and **B**, of user identifiers, so that the map is one-to-many:

> a -> { (b1,t1), (b2, t2), (b3,t3), (b1,t4)  }

which should be read as

> 1. user was observed with identifier A= a and identifier B=b1 at time t1
> 2. then it was observed with A=a and B=b2 at time t2
> 3. Observed with A = a and B=b3 at time t3
> 4. Observed with A =a and again B=b1 at time t4

I have a very big list with this sort of mappings (several millions of different A ids)

Now, the question is the following:

Given a new observation of A = a at some point t, what is the probability that the mapped B-identifier is (b1,b2,b3)? That is, what is the corresponding probability that is one of the previously observed associated B ids?

I'm having trouble figuring out **what sort of machine learning technique suits this problem best**.

Comment: You might find section 3 of Thomas G. Dietterich, [Machine Learning for Sequential Data: A Review](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/publications/mlsd-ssspr.pdf) to be useful.

Comment: @gstvolvr Thank you for that reference--welcome to our site!